# Can't output images in CodeIgniter using html helper

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Im new at CodeIgniter and I want to read some data from mysql database using CodeIgniter. Data I have stored is an image.
I have this folder structure in my aplication:
1.ci

- application

  - controllers
  - views
  - models
  - upload_images (Here I have the images stored as jpg files)
    When I create this code the image shows up and it is Ok:

```html
  echo ' <img src=" http://localhost/ci/'.$row->book_img.' " />'
```

While when I try to output images from the database in another way like below it outputs the link instead of the image. I want to use html helper and I have loaded it.

```html
echo '   img(' http://localhost/ci/'.$row->book_img.')';
```

the image doesn't appear. Do I do something wrong in the second way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The uploads folder should be out side of application folder because the htaccess in the application folder blocks access I also would auto load the url helper

config > autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Folder Structure For Upload Images

```
application

system

upload_images <-- folder permission 0777

index.php
```

then make sure you are getting the image correct on controller `var_dump($row->book_img)`

**Option : 1**

```
$data['img'] = $row->book_img;

$this->load->view('your_view', $data);
```

> View

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('upload_images/' . $img);?>" />
```

**Option: 2**

```
$this->load->helper('html');

$data['img'] = img('upload_images/' . $row->book_img); ;

$this->load->view('your_view', $data);
```

> View

```
<?php echo $img;?>
```

And set your base url

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling it like:

`echo img('http://localhost/ci/'.$row->book_img)`;

[Source](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/html_helper.html#img)

You have syntax errors in your second code snippet and you probably don't have error reporting enabled (which is a bad idea during development). [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) for help with setting that up.

Comment: This doesn't help

Comment: Updated the answer, hopefully that helps. Otherwise, sorry guy.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what what `$row->book_img` is returning. If it is only returning the image name, you must first make sure that is has the extension at the end whether it be `name.jpg` or `name.png`, etc.

if it is correct you simply use:

```
$img_src = base_url () . '/PATH_TO_IMAGE_FOLDER/' . $row->book_img;
echo "<img src='$img_src'/>";
```

If it is returning the full path then:

```
$img_src = base_url () . $row->book_img;
echo "<img src='$img_src'/>";
```